# Image a drive to network share from Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, network-shares, images, dd

I have used both dd and clonezilla to image drives, and that's great for us Linux folks; but I have clients that run Windows and I'd like to be able to be able to either clone to an external drive (I believe there is a GNU dd command I could do this with) or, much preferred, be able to have the cloning happen to a file on a server share.

Is there some type of simple (ideally) command line utility to do something like this under Windows?

Comment: have you tried NFS or SMB share in clonezilla? Works a treat for us and we image both linux and windows machines to the same share.

Comment: I want to be able to image a drive from the command line while windows is running. The idea is to image the drive while the computer is idle over night.  Booting from a CD/DVD/USB memory stick would defeat the purpose, and unless there's something I don't know (possible), Clonezilla does not run under windows.

Comment: @OP you are changing what you want AFTER you make your question so it's hard to hit a moving target. Please edit your answer to define your needs & wants/desires more & why things suggested don't work

Answer (score 0):

I've used linux live (ultimate boot cd) clonezilla years ago to duplicate a windows disk drive to another disk drive, possibly through USB SATA adapter.

1. You want to copy a windows PC while you are booted in windows?
2. you mention storing on a network share, are you wanting like a disk image on a single file?

Option 1: [disk2vhd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd)

Option 2 which is complicated: [MDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/deploy-windows-mdt/get-started-with-the-microsoft-deployment-toolkit), WDS, they rely on Windows ADK I think. This can make an automated thin image from Windows install media then customize. It can also deploy a fat image which is captured/cloned from an existing PC, I believe with DISM a command line tool that saves to a file. DISM may be able to capture image during running windows. It's complicated & makes you redo licensing, but it's 100% made/supported by Microsoft & many many businesses use it. Just might be a bit too heavy for your needs which you have very loosely defined

Comment: Option (1) is 1/2 the answer.  I don't see a specific way to image the vhd back to a physical hard drive, but it ought to be possible. This may be the start of the answer.  Option (2) doesn't really seem to address the idea of being able to make an image of the hard drive from a command line.

Comment: You said clone Windows to drive or file on network share. You then now clarify you want to do that then put it back on a drive. Maybe that's what you mean by clone, but you have to be specific with your question to get specific answers. Please edit your question indicating you want to backup/clone running windows to drive or server then restore that backup/clone to a PC. I explained further on #2 does address you command line image